# Avoid FAB appear above CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I'm trying to put an image on the top of CoordinatorLayout, so it will be half top of the view. it's work fine (attached pic), but when the coordinatorLayout is open to top - the image is get into the coordinatorLayout.
any idea how can i avoid this and keep the image on the top. 
i want the image will get into the background zone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/backgroundLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/TRY3"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinateMainLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="50dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/TRY3"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsingToolBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/innerScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/B1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/whiteLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/B1">

                    </FrameLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/white_plus"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/T103"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/innerScrollView" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

a[image]
[image]

Comment: Add layout_anchor_gravity = "center|top|start".
Although you've anchored your FAB to the scroll view, you haven't set it's gravity. So it'll be just at the top left corner. 
(Sorry for formatting, am on mobile)

Comment: Thanks, but still look the same. the image is look great until i'm scroll all the way up.